# Cheking for duplicate entries for all separate id's in the SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have such SQL table 'logs':

```
id
song_id
file_name
radio_st_id
country
radio_st_name
sent_date
```

I need to check for duplicate radio_st_id entries for all separate song_id's in the table. How to do that?

Thank You very much!

Comment: did you try to group by radio_st_id and get count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Group By` and `Having` clause

```
select song_id,radio_st_id
From yourtable
Group by song_id,radio_st_id
Having count(1) > 1 -- to find the duplicates
```

Comment: I think I like this answer more than mine, the only caveat being if the OP wanted a single list of songs containing duplicates, in which case you would have to subquery your answer, but no big deal.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT song_id,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > COUNT(DISTINCT radio_st_id)
            THEN 'has duplicates'
            ELSE 'no duplicates' END AS num_duplicates
FROM logs
GROUP BY song_id
```

The logic here is that if a given song has duplicate radio stations associated with it, then the total number of radio stations will be greater than the number of distinct radio stations.  If each radio station associated with a song were unique, then these two counts would be equal.

Comment: this would be good but SQL only shows one row: song_id 151, num_duplicates 47. There are more than one song_id, but SQL only shows 1 row

Comment: @Justinas I updated my answer to always show every song.

Comment: It throws me an error: Unrecognized  keyword. (near as) Unexpected token. (near num_duplicates)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
    song_id, COUNT(*)
FROM
    logs
GROUP BY
    song_id
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1